# How to treat a Python object as the value of an attribute of that object?

Tags: python, class

I'm currently writing a Python project in which I need to pass around a custom class representation of an 8-bit byte. I can access an individual byte with `__getitem__()` (for example, the first byte in`my_byte = Byte("00000001")` would be accessed with `my_byte[0]`, returning `1`, since I'm starting at the right), but I would also want to be able to access the value of the byte as a whole. I can access it with a .value property, however that means that if I want to index a list with `my_byte`, then I would need to put `my_list[my_byte.value]`, when I would much rather be able to do `my_list[my_byte]` and have it so that the conversion occurs implicitly there. Additionally, I can set the value of `my_byte` with a setter, but I also need to set that as `my_byte.value`, which is again clunkier than I would like, when I would prefer to be able to set the value of `my_byte` with just `my_byte = 42`.

There are a variety of reasons for it, but I would rather use this custom representation of a Byte for this project. If I have to use `my_byte.value` so be it, but I'm really hoping there's a solution I'm just missing.

I would have assumed it would have been some kind of dunder method to define this kind of behavior, but I don't think any of them do what I'm intending to do. This is a current sample of a more basic version of my current Byte representation, missing non-relevant parts:

```py
class Byte:
  def __init__(self):
    self.bits = [0 for _ in range(8)]

  @property
  def value(self):
    return sum((2**i * self.bits[7-i] for i in range(7, -1, -1)))

  @value.setter
  def value(self, value):
    for i in range(7, -1, -1):
      if value >= 2**i:
        value -= 2**i
        self.bits[7-i] = 1
      else:
        self.bits[7-i] = 0

#Current behavior:
>> my_byte = Byte()
>> my_byte.value = 42
>> my_byte.value
42

#Intended behavior:
>> my_byte = Byte()
>> my_byte = 42
>> my_byte
42
```

Comment: You can't do this, names refer to objects. `my_byte` cannot simultanously refer to your `Byte` object and then, at the same time, some `int` object.

Comment: "I would have assumed it would have been some kind of dunder method to define this kind of behavior" why would this kind of behavior exist at all? It would be totally chaotic. How are yousupposed to know if you want the object or the value? The closest I can come up with is something like a union in C, but that's more about static typing and different interpretations of the bits in some raw piece of memory. But even that isn't really like what you are asking for here (and even for a C union, you need something like `data.whatever`)

Comment: Now, *if specifically* you want it for the case of using your object as an index to a list or other built-in sequence (`range`, `tuple`, `str`, `bytes`), you can implement the `__index__` method, e.g if `class Foo:` implements `def __index__(self): return 0` then `[1,2,3][Foo()]` would return `1`,  but it sounds like you want this to work generally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work *in general*, but for indexing (and any more explicit conversions to integer), the `__index__` special method will do what you want. Just define it, taking only `self` as an argument, and have it return an `int` converted from the value stored, e.g.:

```
class Byte:
  def __init__(self):
    self.bits = [0 for _ in range(8)]

  @property
  def value(self):
    return sum((2**i * self.bits[7-i] for i in range(7, -1, -1)))

  @value.setter
  def value(self, value):
    for i in range(7, -1, -1):
      if value >= 2**i:
        value -= 2**i
        self.bits[7-i] = 1
      else:
        self.bits[7-i] = 0

  def __index__(self):
    return self.value
```

Having done that, `my_list[my_byte]` will just work. On modern Python, you can also do `int(my_byte)` to explicitly convert to `int` (on older Python, you can do `__int__ = __index__` within the class definition to support `int`) and it will work with the `operator.index` function (which is how you explicitly ask to convert to an `int`-like thing to a true `int`, without the lossy coercion calling `int` itself will do for `float`s and `str` and the like).

Now, as noted, this won't make it seamlessly behave like an `int` in *every* circumstance. If you want that, and don't want to inherit from `int` (given you're writing a mutable type, that won't work), you're going to have to write your own [subclass of `numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral). It's more work, and I strongly recommend looking at [the source code for `fractions.Fraction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/fractions.py) before you begin. The module was written, at least in part, to be a guide to developing your own custom numeric types in a way that doesn't involve hand-writing every single mathematical operator overload entirely from scratch. It's still a lot, but the system of defining a *single* method to do each overload, then using the `_operator_fallbacks` helper to convert it to both the forward and reversed version of each operator halves the work you'd need to do writing each function from scratch.

Comment: This is probably 95% of what I need, so I suppose I'll close the issue and call this as good as it's going to get. Most of it is using the Byte as an index into a list, so if I can streamline that without going insane that's probably as good as it's gonna get.